# Add products to cart using drag & drop in magento

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, magento, magento-1.7, jquery-droppable

I want to add products to cart using Drag & drop. 
For that I am using jQuery UI Droppable . Code is:-

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
     $(function() {
$( ".category-products" ).accordion();
$( ".product-name" ).draggable({
  appendTo: "body",
  helper: "clone"
});
$( ".block-content ol" ).droppable({
  activeClass: "ui-state-default",
  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
  accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
    $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
  }
}).sortable({
  items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
  sort: function() {
    // gets added unintentionally by droppable interacting with sortable
    // using connectWithSortable fixes this, but doesn't allow you to customize active/hoverClass options
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
  }
});
```

});

Using this code products name become droppable to cart but they are not added to cart. I try but don’t able to add product name to cart. Please help me.

Comment: Does these products have any product options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your product dont have any custom option.

Store your product id as an hidden field within you product list (draggable li)

```
      <li>Lolcat Shirt
          <input type='hidden' value='2' name='pid' />
      </li>
```

Then do

```
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this )
      .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
      .find( "> p" )
        .html( "Dropped!" );

    add product to cart
    p_id = ui.draggable.find('input[name="pid"]').val();
    $.get("/path/to/app/checkout/cart/add?qty=1&product=" + p_id)

    return false;
  }
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/C2Ufk/

You will need to do something similar to remove item

Comment: Thanks for answer. Product name & shopping cart box is in different phtml file. when I will pass p_id value then it show undefined value. please help me

Comment: Since this is do using javascript it should not make a different which phtml files it is in. Please add a screenshot so I can have a better understanding of what your trying to do

Comment: Sorry I got the mistake. Now I am getting proper url in alert box.

Comment: Now I am getting url but I have to add product to cart. I think for that I have to use ajax to add products to cart. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I got one module for the same..

[Drag & Drop Sort Products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/drag-drop-sort-products.html) for which it works fine for me.. and really great development.